# DataGridView Selected Cell Default Color

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors, rgb

Does anyone know the RGB code of DataGridView's selected cell background color. I'm currently trying to make certain cells appear to be blank until a certain condition is satisfied. Handling the 'unselected' `ForeColor` was easy as all it required was `Color.White`. But handling the `SelectionForeColor` has not been the easiest. The closest default color that I have found is `Color.DodgerBlue`.

I've referenced this [site](http://www.flounder.com/csharp_color_table.htm), but it appears that I am out of luck when it comes to a provided color.

Below is the color that I am referring to.

[image]

I feel that there must be a way to access this property? But how? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The color that I was looking for was: `SystemColors.Highlight`.

If you go to the `Properties` section of your `DataGridView` object. There is a property called `DefaultCellStyle` and under that there is a section called `Appearance` where the `SelectionBackColor` property resides. The default for `SelectionBackColor` is `Highlight` which is under `System.Drawing.SystemColors`.

Answer (score 3):

One property to try is `DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor`, although you may be more interested in `DataGridViewCell.InheritedStyle.SelectionBackColor`.